# Why is the client trying to require a library when I am doing server side rendering?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, server-side-rendering

I am trying to implement server side rendering on my react app, but having trouble with this one error.[image]
this is my webpack.config.js file. When I run the script `npm start` everything compiles correctly.

```
var fs = require('fs');

var nodeModules = {};
fs.readdirSync('node_modules')
  .filter(function(x) {
    return ['.bin'].indexOf(x) === -1;
  })
  .forEach(function(mod) {
    nodeModules[mod] = 'commonjs ' + mod;
  });



module.exports = {
  entry: [
    './server.js'
  ],
  target: 'node',
  output: {
    path: __dirname,
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  externals: nodeModules,
  module: {
    loaders: [{
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      loader: 'babel',
      query: {
        presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'stage-1']
      }
    }]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
  },
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    contentBase: './'
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the main issue is that webpack thinks bundle.js is build for node environment. Therefore it assumes that require is available. However it is meant for the browser, it will throw an error since require is not available. I'm not really sure if your webpack.config.js is for the server or the browser, since the entry point is the server.js and yet the output is for bundle.js, which I assume meant for the browser.

Have a look on server rendering tutorial [here](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-tutorial/tree/master/lessons/13-server-rendering). Basically, you have to have a webpack config file for server and the browser. The server webpack config file would have an entry point where your server is defined. Whereas the browser webpack config file would have an entry point where `react-dom` render method is called. Then, make sure that the output of the browser webpack config is the one that is used in the html and not the server one.

Comment: Ok that makes much more sense. So I will have a webpack.config.js for the client side AND a webpack.server.config.js for the server side?

Comment: @joethemow Yup. Make sure that you also run the build command for both client and server bundle.

Comment: So I am using the script in the tutorial link you provided. the npm start:prod would do that correct?

Comment: @joethemow that will run the build for both client and server and subsequently run the production server. If you want to only build the code bundle, just do npm run build

Comment: ok perfect. Any idea how to fix this? `window is not defined`. I understand why the error occurs, not sure how to fix thought.

Comment: I don't know why it is appearing in the server.bundle.js file if it is in the app.js file a file that should be using the client webpack

Comment: Do you have the code on GitHub or somewhere? That happens because somewhere in your server code you are using window object, which is not available in node. Make sure you are configuring the build path of your webpack correctly and make sure that the files that uses window does not get required in the server bundle.

Comment: Ok so I think I see the issue. I am requiring my routes file which uses the app file as its component and the app file uses the window. Any idea on how to fix?

Comment: @joethemow It is really hard to debug the code without looking at the code. If you have the code somewhere I can see, I might be able to help you.